# Traversing a directory tree bottom-up using Python

Tags: python, os.walk, os.path

I would like to find a way to traverse a directory tree in a bottom-up fashion using Python.  The goal would be to find a single directory that would be an unknown distance above or below the current directory.

I made a diagram that I hope makes my question more clear: 
[image: Directory Tree]

The red box is the starting point and the green boxes are possible locations of the destination folder, of which only one needs to be found, not both.

If the destination box is /One/_One/_One, then I would expect the script to go up to /One, then traverse all the way down into /One/_One/_One.

If the destination folder is /Three, then I would expect the script to do the same as above, and then proceed to /Two and /Two/_Two, not finding it, and then finally reaching /Three. Alternatively, after checking all of /One, it would go to / and then find /Three, skipping the traversal of /Two.

Any help would be appreciated.  I have been looking at all of the os.path and os.walk methods, but haven't found my solution yet.

Comment: I am having a hard time following the kind of traversal you want this thing to make. It seems to me like it would just eventually explore your entire file system?

Comment: It would eventually do so, yes.  For os.walk, usually you look for a folder that is somewhere below your current directory, for this I would like it to start at the bottom, and search for the directory upwards.

Comment: your text doesn't correspond to the diagram. What is the end (final/sought-after) node in the diagram? How is it specified (basename, several path parts, something else)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key to this lies in the following documentation for [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories):

> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames

Armed with that, you simply have to think of this problem as a tree-search where you start with the root at the first node, and every time you don't find the solution, you pop up a level and perform a tree search again, *removing the node that was the root of your last search when you get there*.

Let's say I have the following:

```
start_path    = 'ABC0123/Comp/Scripts'
searching_for ='Some_File'
```

I can do the following:

```
last_root    = start_path
current_root = start_path
found_path   = None
while found_path is None and current_root:
    pruned = False
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(current_root):
        if not pruned:
           try:
              # Remove the part of the tree we already searched
              del dirs[dirs.index(os.path.basename(last_root))]
              pruned = True
           except ValueError:
              pass
        if searching_for in files:
           # found the file, stop
           found_path = os.path.join(root, searching_for)
           break
     # Otherwise, pop up a level, search again
     last_root    = current_root
     current_root = os.path.dirname(last_root)
```

The first iteration this should search the `'ABC0123/Comp/Scripts'` directory. Then, if it doesn't find `'Some_File'`, it will search the `'ABC0123/Comp'` directory, skipping the 'Scripts' directory. And then it will search the `'ABC0123'` directory, skipping `'Comp'` and everything underneath it.

Here's some example output of the traversal. `CR` is `current_root`, `LR` is `last_root`, and `Exploring` is the `root` in the current step of the `walk`. In this case the file was in `ABC0123/Paint/Output`:

```
CR: 'ABC0123/Comp/Scripts/', LR: 'ABC0123/Comp/Scripts/'
Exploring: 'ABC0123/Comp/Scripts/'
CR: 'ABC0123/Comp/Scripts', LR: 'ABC0123/Comp/Scripts/'
Exploring: 'ABC0123/Comp/Scripts'
CR: 'ABC0123/Comp', LR: 'ABC0123/Comp/Scripts'
Exploring: 'ABC0123/Comp'
Exploring: 'ABC0123/Comp/Output'
CR: 'ABC0123', LR: 'ABC0123/Comp'
Exploring: 'ABC0123'
Exploring: 'ABC0123/Lighting'
Exploring: 'ABC0123/Lighting/Output'
Exploring: 'ABC0123/Paint'
Exploring: 'ABC0123/Paint/Output'

>>> found_path
'ABC0123/Paint/Output/Some_File'
```

Also note that it's not really clear if you're searching for a directory or a file. My code assumes that latter, but if it's the former simply change:

```
if searching_for in files:
```

to

```
if searching_for in dirs:
```

But note that in both cases, it's assuming there is a single, globally (within the max tree depth) unique file/dir you are searching for, or that the first instance of that file/dir you come across is the one you're looking for. For example, as written you couldn't search for 'Paint/Output' specifically. You should be able to pretty easily figure out how to modify the search conditions to allow this however.

Comment: it says to use topdown = true but in the sample code it's  not the case ...